# Apache two RewriteRules dependant

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a ecommerce site which I want to make it multilingual. By now English has been used as a defualt language. The next URL's are being working porperly and were indexed by Google.

```
* example.com/article/id-item
```

As I need to make it multilingual, the url's need to be in this way:

```
* example.com/en/article/id-item -> which is language default
* example.com/fr/article/id-item
* example.com/de/article/id-item
```

Because I don't want to be punished by google because my current url is pretty well indexed, inestead of using http://example.com/en/article/id-item I want to use the current URL for English Language, so my URL's should be in this way:

```
* example.com/article/id-item -> English
* example.com/fr/article/id-item -> French
* example.com/de/article/id-item -> German
```

But internally, to be routed properly with symfony, I need these internal redirect (not seen in browser address box):

```
* example.com/index.php/en/article/id-item -> English
* example.com/index.php/fr/article/id-item -> French
* example.com/index.php/de/article/id-item -> German
```

SO I've been testing my .htaccess and it doesn't work porperly:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index\.php/(en|fr|de)
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/?.*)$ en/$1 [L]
```

This can be tested in: http://htaccess.mwl.be/ using url example.com/article/id-item as a sample

The results are:
Output url

example.com/index.php/article/id-item
Debugging info

1   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f This condition was met.

2   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d This condition was met.

3   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php This condition was met.

4   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 The new url is example.com/index.php/article/id-item

5   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f This condition was met.

6   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^index.php/(en|fr|de)   This condition is not met.

7   RewriteRule ^index.php(/?.*)$ en/$1 [L]    This rule was not met.

I don't uderstand why in rule 6, REQUEST_URI is not the result of rule 4.

Does anyone have any idea about what it could happen?

Answer (score 0):

With this piece of code, I think  I have my rewrittings done:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?(en|fr|de)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ en/$1 [QSA,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "index.php/$1" [QSA,L]
```

But the main probplem is in Symfony/HttpFoundation Request  Object, due to this:
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/15354